# TypeError NoneType when performing subtraction on dict values

Tags: python, nonetype

I have a script that does the following

- subtracts values in a dict's key
- convertes array to a sorted list
- subtracting the first value from the second
- then the second from the third
- and so on.

The problem is some of the values are null in the source data and this throws a `TypeError`. I tried to throw in a condition but it still attempts to subtract Nones.

Here is the code with some sample data:

```
eLinks = {'726122193.0': [1310, 1315, 1320, 1325, 1330, 1335, 1340, 1310, 1315, 1320, 1325, 1330, 1335, 1340, 1310, 1315, 1320, 1325, 1330, 1335, 1340, 1310, 1315, 1320, 1325, 1330, 1335, 1340, 1310, 1315, 1320, 1325, 1330, 1335, 1340, 1310, 1315, 1320, 1325, 1330, 1335, 1340, 1310, 1315, 1320, 1325, 1330, 1335, 1340, 1310, 1315, 1320, 1325, 1330, 1335, 1340, 1310, 1315, 1320, 1325, 1330, 1335, 1340, 1310, 1315, 1320, 1325, 1330, 1335, 1340, 1310, 1315, 1320, 1325, 1330, 1335, 1340, 1310, 1315, 1320, 1325, 1330, 1335, 1340, 1310, 1315, 1320, 1325, 1330, 1335, 1340], '23607015.0': [None, None, None, 90, 95, 130, 2070, None, None, None, 580, 585, 610, 615, 2355, 2360, 1945, 1950, 125, 130, None, None, None, None, None, None, 90, 95, 130, 2070, None, None, None, 580, 585, 610, 615, 2355, 2360, 1945, 1950, 125, 130, None, None, None, None, None, None, 90, 95, 130, 2070, None, None, None, 580, 585, 610, 615, 2355, 2360, 1945, 1950, 125, 130, None, None, None, None, None, None, 90, 95, 130, 2070, None, None, None, 580, 585, 610, 615, 2355, 2360, 1945, 1950, 125, 130, None, None, None, None, None, None, 90, 95, 130, 2070, None, None, None, 580, 585, 610, 615, 2355, 2360, 1945, 1950, 125, 130, None, None, None, None, None, None, 90, 95, 130, 2070, None, None, None, 580, 585, 610, 615, 2355, 2360, 1945, 1950, 125, 130, None, None, None, None, None, None, 90, 95, 130, 2070, None, None, None, 580, 585, 610, 615, 2355, 2360, 1945, 1950, 125, 130, None, None, None, None, None, None, 90, 95, 130, 2070, None, None, None, 580, 585, 610, 615, 2355, 2360, 1945, 1950, 125, 130, None, None, None, None, None, None, 90, 95, 130, 2070, None, None, None, 580, 585, 610, 615, 2355, 2360, 1945, 1950, 125, 130, None, None, None, None, None, None, 90, 95, 130, 2070, None, None, None, 580, 585, 610, 615, 2355, 2360, 1945, 1950, 125, 130, None, None, None, None, None, None, 90, 95, 130, 2070, None, None, None, 580, 585, 610, 615, 2355, 2360, 1945, 1950, 125, 130, None, None, None, None, None, None, 90, 95, 130, 2070, None, None, None, 580, 585, 610, 615, 2355, 2360, 1945, 1950, 125, 130, None, None, None, None, None, None, 90, 95, 130, 2070, None, None, None, 580, 585, 610, 615, 2355, 2360, 1945, 1950, 125, 130, None, None, None]}

eOut = {}
for key, lis in eLinks.iteritems():
    eCheck = []
    sLis = sorted(lis)
    for i, _ in enumerate(sLis[:-1]):
        if i is not None:
            dif = sLis[i+1] - sLis[i]
            if dif > 20:
                eCheck.append(dif)
            eOut[key] = eCheck
```

Comment: You''re comparing `None` types.

Comment: Why don't you simply first remove the Nones prior to processing?

Comment: @John Coleman This data is being generated from an ESRI featureclass with thousands of keys. This is just a small sample of it. It would not be feasible to remove Nones each time I ran the script.

Comment: I think the laste line is indented one level too much as well.

Comment: In Python 2, after sorting all of the Nones will be at the front of the list. Just slice them out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could slice away the `None` values after you sort, and then not worry about identifying `None` in the inner loop:

```
eOut = {}
for key, lis in eLinks.iteritems():
    eCheck = []
    sLis = sorted(lis)
    sLis = sLis[sLis.count(None):]
    for i, _ in enumerate(sLis[:-1]):
        dif = sLis[i+1] - sLis[i]
        if dif > 20:
            eCheck.append(dif)
            eOut[key] = eCheck
```

With your sample data, `eOut` becomes:

```
{'23607015.0': [30, 450, 25, 1330, 120, 285]}
```

Comment: Thanks John. I like the fix before the conditional.

Answer (score 1):

You clearly didn't mean to check for

```
if i is not None:
```

`i` is never `None` (it comes from the `enumerate`), while you want to make sure, neither `sLis[i+1]` nor `sLis[i]` are `None`.

The immediate bugfix is to replace the above line with:

```
if sLis[i+1] is not None and sLis[i] is not None:
```

---

A cleaner version would be something like this:

```
e_links = {'726122193.0': [1310, 1315, 1320, …

result = {}
for key, links in e_links.iteritems():
    links = sorted(l for l in links if l is not None)
    pairs = zip(links, links[1:])
    result[key] = [b-a for a, b in pairs if b-a>20]
```

Comment: Thanks Hop. Your solution worked but I prefer John Coleman's fix outside of the conditional.